# Openlayers obtaining centroid of a vector layer feature and using it to set the center of the map

Tags: openlayers, kml

The code below uses an absolute position for the center of the map but I want to set the center according to the vector layer feature brought in from the KML file - is this possible? I've looked at getCentroid but can't get the syntax right?

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map("Map");
var mapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
//Set centre position converting from WGS to Mercator
var wgs84 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   // Transform from WGS 1984
var toProjection   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection
var position       = new OpenLayers.LonLat(4.891280,52.373690).transform( fromProjection, toProjection);

var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("vectorlayer", {
    projection: wgs84,
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url: "kmlfile.kml",   //<-- relative or absolute URL to your .osm file
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML()
    }),
    styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
      "default": {
            //pointRadius: "${radius}",
            fillColor: "blue",
            fillOpacity: 0.1,
            strokeColor: "#5555ff",
            strokeWidth: 2,
            strokeOpacity: 0.8
       }
        ,
      "select": {
          fillColor: "#8aeeef",
          strokeColor: "#32a8a9"
      }
    })
});

map.addLayers([mapnik, layer]);

map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());

var scaleline = new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine();
map.addControl(scaleline);


//Set centre of map and zoom level
map.setCenter(position, 10 );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this (where layer is your vector based on your code):

```
var bounds = layer.geometry.bounds;
map.zoomToExtent(bounds);
```

or

```
var bounds = layer.geometry.bounds;
map.setCenter(bounds.getCenterLonLat());
```

Comment: Gery, That does not work - map loads but I just get white screen for map and scale is at 10000km - if I zoom in once then world map comes up and not centred on KML feature.

Comment: and if you replace `bounds` by `layer`?